# In Python, what does object(**config) do?

Tags: python, neural-network, evolutionary-algorithm

Can someone please help explain what this means.

Background: 'network' is a class and represents a Neural Network object, it's constructor requires several inputs such as; nodes, inputs, outputs, num_functions etc. However, the python implementation I'm using as a reference uses a dictionary to load these parameters into the constructor (I believe that is whats going on). Can anyone help explain how this works **network(**config)**? Ps. I'm converting this to Java.

The constructor for the network class looks like this:

```
public network(int _graph_length, int _input_length, int _output_length, int _max_arity, int _function_length){
```

The dictionaries do this:

```
output is a dictionary used to store data.
config is a dictionary uses to load parameters for the NN.
```

And the code I don't understand is:

```
//Output data reset:
output.put("skipped", 0);
output.put("estimated", 0);

//if single mutation method:
if (config.get("speed") == "single"){       
    network.mutate = network.one_active_mutation;
    }

    parent = network(**config);
    yield parent;
while true: 
    //code to evolve networks here!
```

Comment: This is Python syntax and not specific to the neural networking library you're using.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks! So parent is loaded with unspecified parameters, using a named argument?

Comment: `config` is expected to be a dictionary, and it's keys and values are used to call `network()` with keyword parameters. Looking at the `network()` signature, `config` *must* have those 5 parameters as key-value pairs for this to work, since none of those are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`network(**config)` will unpack the dictionary `config` and use the key value pairs in that dictionary as arguments to `network`.

For example, these will all make the same call to `func`:

```
def func(foo, bar):
    print foo, bar

d = {'foo': 'value1', 'bar': 'value2'}

func(**d)
func(**{'bar': 'value2', 'foo': 'value1'})
func(bar='value2', foo='value1')
func('value1', 'value2')
```